# How to use mutations in react-apollo-hooks and formik?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, formik, react-apollo-hooks

In my many attempts, I've tried to use react-apollo-hooks and formik together but it seems impossible. The data from the forms is only available in the `<Formik>` tag, and is otherwise inaccessible outside of it. Also I can't call my `useMutation` hook and pass arguments to it at the same time:

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // The react-apollo-hook for useMutation
  // Its not hard to call this, but it seems impossible to call it,
  // with any sort of arguments.
  // It seems pointless not being able to pass in data from the form
  const [createUser, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      firstName: '???',
      lastName: '???',
      email: '???',
      password: '???',
    },
  });
  // Formik stuff goes down here. It's impossible to call `useMutation` 
  // with the argument of `values`
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        showPassword: false,
      }}
      // This is the part that calls the hook.
      // I see no way of passing arguments to `useMutation` from here
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => createUser}
      render={({submitForm, isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue}) => (
        <div>
          <h1>Sign up for a new account</h1>
          <Form className={classes.container}>
            <Field
              className={classes.textField}
              name="firstName"
              type="text"
              label="First name"
              margin="dense"
              variant="outlined"
              component={TextField}
            />
          </Form>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            margin="dense"
            className={classes.button}
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            onClick={submitForm}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );

};
```

So how would I somehow be able to pass arguments to the `useMutation` part at the top, from `onSubmit`? It seems impossible to pass arguments to the hook. I don't think I can add any other data outside of the query name `CREATE_USER_MUTATION` and the objects which has the settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutation variables can be provided to the individual mutation call instead of the `useMutation` call. So you can do this at the top of your component:

```
const [createUser, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION)
```

and then provide the variables once you actually call `createUser`:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => createUser({ variables: values })}
```

Comment: I found a workaround earlier, which relied on something inefficient that relied on using React `useState`, setting all the fields in an onSubmit function, and using `useEffect` to call `createUser` only after all the fields have been updated (since its async). But its obviously inefficient and requires lots of lines of code. Your solution is much more cleaner and simple!